# Binding on Height property in WPF Window, not firing when there is a Width property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
Title="{x:Static prop:Resources.Window1}" 
Height="{Binding WindowHeight}"
MinHeight="{Binding WindowMinHeight}"
MinWidth="500">
```

The getter of `WindowHeight` fires as expected.

But when I add:

```
Width="750"
```

to the XAML .. :

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
Title="{x:Static prop:Resources.Window1}" 
Height="{Binding WindowHeight}"
MinHeight="{Binding WindowMinHeight}"
Width="750"
MinWidth="500">
```

.. the getter for `WindowHeight` does not fire.

Why is this?

Thanks, Joe

Comment: `Width` does not affect `Height`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:WpfToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
Title="{x:Static prop:Resources.Window1}"
Height="300"
Width="{Binding Height, ElementName=window}">
```

Comment: Why would I bind the Width to Height?